# List view messing up on scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I know there are numerous answers to this question on stackoverflow, and I did go through as many as i found. But, I did not land to any solution for my problem.

My problem:

I am making an attendance system for a startup. second activity in app, takes employee data from sql server and display them in the list. my list item has a text view and a button in it. Button displays the status of employee. Now, when I click the button, there is a duplicacy in state change of the button. suppose i do it for 1 item then it occurs for another item in the list when being scrolled.

what  I tried:

studied the concept of custom adapter and overriding the get view in adapter class.
studied recycling concept in list view and holder concept.

still not able to solve. please suggest something.

Here is the code from the adapter class:

```
package mywork.attendance_system;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Harshul on 8/24/2015.
 */
public class custom_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
   // private int[] colors;
    ArrayList<String> emp;
    //ArrayList<Boolean> status;

    public custom_adapter(Activity activity , ArrayList<String> items)
        {
            super(activity, R.layout.rowlayout, items);
            inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
            emp=items;
      //      this.status=status;
            Log.d("1111",emp.get(1));
           // this.colors[0]=Color.parseColor("#FFFFF");
           // this.colors[1]=Color.parseColor("#D2E4FC");
        }

    static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView tview;
        public Button b1;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){
       ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView==null)
        {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tview=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
        viewHolder.b1=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.A);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
else
        {
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        final ViewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;
        viewHolder.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                LinearLayout parentRow = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
                ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
                final int position1 = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);

                if((finalViewHolder.b1.getText()).equals("A")) {
                    finalViewHolder.b1.setText("P");
                    //            status.set(position1,true);
                    //          Log.d("statussss",String.valueOf(status.get(position1)));
                }
                else {
                    finalViewHolder.b1.setText("A");
                    //        status.set(position1,false);
                    //      Log.d("statussss",String.valueOf(status.get(position1)));
                }
            }});


        finalViewHolder.tview.setText(String.valueOf(emp.get(position)));

        if (position%2==1)
        {
            finalViewHolder.tview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F0F0F0"));
        }
        else
        {
            finalViewHolder.tview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D2E4FC"));
        }



            return convertView;

        }

    }
```

My xml file for layout of the list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="237dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textColor="#222222"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:text="A"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

if you need anything else just say, i will upload it.

[image: how my screen looks like]
[image: duplicacy]

Comment: ArrayList<String> emp; should be    ArrayList<Employee> emp; and Employe has name and isActive fields, use isActive for button. Could you try that.

Comment: @sedpol -  may you suggest me with some example or any reference to code. I did not get it.

Comment: @harshuljain you have a google for examples. It's a best place for finding it.

Comment: @harshuljain when I googled "android list example with button", I found this -> https://looksok.wordpress.com/tag/listview-item-with-button/ it will be good reference for you.

Answer (score 1):

So, This is what I did to remove the bug...

1. removed the convertview==null condition.
2. stored the status of button in a seperate list and extracted the status from the list.

   ```
   **ArrayList<String> status;**

   **public custom_adapter(Activity activity , ArrayList<String> items,ArrayList<String> statusc)**
       {
           super(activity, R.layout.rowlayout, items);
           inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
           emp=items;
           **status=statusc;**

       }

   static class ViewHolder{
       public TextView tview;
       public Button b1;

   }
   @Override
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){
      ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
       viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
       viewHolder.tview=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
       viewHolder.b1=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.A);
       **viewHolder.b1.setText(status.get(position));**
       convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

       final ViewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;
       viewHolder.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               LinearLayout parentRow = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
               ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
               final int position1 = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);

               if((finalViewHolder.b1.getText()).equals("A")) {
                   finalViewHolder.b1.setText("P");
                   **status.set(position,"P");**

               }
               else {
                   finalViewHolder.b1.setText("A");
                   **status.set(position,"A");**
               }
           }});


       finalViewHolder.tview.setText(String.valueOf(emp.get(position)));

       if (position%2==1)
       {
           finalViewHolder.tview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F0F0F0"));
       }
       else
       {
           finalViewHolder.tview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D2E4FC"));
       }



           return convertView;

       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if((v.getText()).equals("A")) {
            v.setText("P");
        }
        else {
            v.setText("A");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is because you are taking the **Position** variable from the getView,which gives you the position of the element rendered on the screen at any given time and not the position of that element in your database.

What you can do is you can have unique element in db apart from the index,when you are populating the Ui you can add that as a part of it.
So when you do get a element of Position 'x' you can fetch the entry and compare the unique element with that of the db so that you can get the correct entry.

Answer (score 0):

Use final viewholder variable for setOnClickListener

In your case use:

```
finalviewHolder.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() ...
```

instead of

```
viewHolder.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() ....
```

remove Hard code text from your textview

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:text="A"// Remove this line
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />
```